# Animating an Illustrator Line in After Effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-after-effects, animate

I'm trying to animate a coiled-up looking line into a more relaxed loose looking line.  I figured out how to do this in AfterEffects (I opened the Path 1 option and was able to move individual points).  But I created this line in Illustrator, with a specific color and a gradient near the tip.  When I import the Illustrator file into AfterEffects, I no longer have control over vertices.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I guess another option would be to figure out how to add a gradient to the line i created in After-Effects...  the line has many curves, and the whole thing needs to be blue, but the end needs to be a different color...

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your question. Could you show us what you have, and what you've already tried? Have your tried doing a web search, and what results did it yield? We'll be able to help much more easily if we know what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: I would suggest you ask this question at http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm confused you say you no longer have control over vertices but that you were able to fix the shape within Path 1. Is it the color then that you're struggling with or what?